# load an editor multiple times

Tags: php, javascript, textarea, yui

I use the YUI Rich Text Editor, I load it via javascript:

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('comments', {
height: '80px',
width: '600px',
dompath: false, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
animate: true,
});
myEditor.render();
```

now I want to attach it to multiple textarea like this:

```
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments" . $issue_id . "' style='width: 600px; height: 80px;' onfocus=\"findField('comments" . $issue_id . "')\">" . $comments . "</textarea>";
```

How can I put in the script something like `'comments" . $issue_id . "'` ? 
Can someone give me a tip on how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: So you need to generate the JavaScript dynamically too to instantiate the textarea's in the DOM?  What are you having trouble with exactly?  Seen this demo? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/multi_editor.html

Comment: I have seen the demo but I just simply don't know how to proceed...

Comment: You would probably want to have an array type structure containing details on the WYSIWYG editors you will want to render.  Iterating over that structure you will need to output the HTML markup for each one and either a snippet of JS code corresponding to each or some dynamic JS to parse the DOM for all textarea's (say by class).  Short of writing code for you not sure how to better explain it.

Comment: OK thank you, I will give it a try, not sure I totally understood that. Can you do like a small example using code ? Thanks a lot ficuscr for your help.

Comment: Done it. Some buttons in some editor's textarea are hidden and I've no idea why, but it works, I'll have a look on the next problem...Thanks a lot anyway